# What is the solution to avoid downvotes again & again on asked question?

Tags: discussion, subjective-questions, votes, down-votes

Suppose someone have asked a Question on stackExchange & Other users reported as its not a good question, few of them says it's an opinion based question & getting downvotes again and again on that question. There are few answers are availabe in that asked question. So What is the solution to avoid downvotes again & again. 
Could he/she delete his question?

> But my problem is that, questions having number of answers never deletes. How to overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to avoid asking a question that's likely to get downvoted?  Or how to prevent a question what already has a few downvotes from getting more downvotes? Or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions are generally only deleted by moderators (diamonds or high-rep users) when they actively cause harm to the site itself. Examples are spam, racism and other discriminatory behavior), intentional misconduct, and of course anything that might be considered fun. [We hate fun.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) Causing minor harm to a user's reputation is not a reason why a delete vote would be cast by *us*. Any user can delete their own post at any time for any reason.

As for how to prevent downvotes in general:

- Make your questions clear and answerable
- Make your answers clear and on-topic
- Heed the feedback of other users suggesting you clarify, reword, or even remove parts of your post
- When asking a question, don't post right away - read it after 20-30 minutes as if you've never seen it before. I personally find this answers over half the questions I type and then I don't even need to post them.
- Edit, edit, edit!! Editing your posts and always making them better is the number one way to increase signal to noise ratio which is where reptuation comes from.
- Ask questions here on Meta when unsure of policies, procedures, and customs (which you've clearly started doing already)

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks for your help. Now my question is- How to delete that question. Could they ask to moderator for deleting? can moderator consider it & delete the question?

Comment: Moderators can. For example, you recently flagged a question asking it to be deleted. I declined it because it wasn't one that I felt needed to be deleted. If you find spam or active harm, definitely flag those. If it is your *own* then you will find the delete button in between the edit and flag buttons.

Comment: Own questions could not be deleted if it has answered someone, Means we cant delete it, even if we try to click on delete button

Comment: Interesting. I just tried it out (on a site I'm not a moderator on, obviously) and it did indeed block me. I'll keep that in mind for future flags as I was unaware of this 'feature'.